# How to manage SVN in Xcode 5.1.1?

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control

I would like to send a code to a SVN server using Xcode. I found that Xcode 4 has in Provisioning Profile a tool to manage SVN (creating folders & pulling the code). Now in Xcode 5 they change it and added Source Control.

I added my SVN server address (inlucding name and password) in Preferences -> Accounts but each time I try to commit and pull files to SVN server there is an information "No remotes found".

How can I solve it ? How can I manage the structure of folders in SVN using Xcode ?

I do not want to use other programms.

Comment: How are you trying to commit/pull files?

Comment: Source Control -> Commit and than Source Control -> Pull