# Xcode 5.1.1 and SVN problems

Tags: xcode, svn

I would like to send a code to a SVN server using Xcode. I found that Xcode 4 has in Provisioning Profile a tool to manage SVN (creating folders & pulling the code). Now in Xcode 5 they change it and added Source Control.

I added my SVN server address (inlucding name and password) in Preferences -> Accounts but each time I try to commit and pull files to SVN server there is an information "No remotes found".

How can I solve it ? How can I manage the structure of folders in SVN using Xcode ?

I tried to resume [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154219/how-to-manage-svn-in-xcode-5-1-1) post but my intervention has been deleted, as it was not an answer. I can't add a bounty (not enough reputation) and can't add a comment (same issue) so what am I supposed to do if not adding an answer or adding a new question for the same problem?